# OpenLayers: Querying pixels in a TileImage source without showing the layer on the map

Tags: openlayers

In OpenLayers 4.6.5, I'm trying to read pixel values from a TileImage source without actually rendering the source as a layer on the map. I've been trying to adapt some code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220254/is-it-possible-to-get-pixel-values-from-ol-source-raster-on-mouse-over) as follows - note that at this stage I'm only up to the point of checking whether the tile exists, and haven't gone as far as to actually query the tile yet:

```js
window['tiles'] = {};

window["L8SourceNRG"] = new ol.source.TileImage({
    url: NRGtileURL,
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    transition: 0,
    preload: Infinity,
    tileGrid: L8SourceTileGrid
});

window["L8SourceNRG"].on("tileloadend", (e) => {
    console.log('tileloadend event fired');
    let coord = e.tile.getTileCoord();
    window['tiles'][coord.join('-')] = e.tile.getImage();
});

map.on('pointermove', (evt) => {
    if (evt.dragging) {
        return;
    }

    let coordinate = ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, map.getView().getProjection(), ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857'));

    let tileCoord = L8SourceTileGrid.getTileCoordForCoordAndResolution(coordinate, this.map.getView().getResolution());
    let key = tileCoord.join('-');
    if (key in window['tiles']) {
        console.log('key in tiles');
    }
});
```

With the above code alone, the console log message "key in tiles" never appears. I can only get that to show up if I've already loaded my "L8SourceNRG" source into a layer and rendered that on the map. But I don't want to show it on the map - I just want to use the pixel values to run some calculations which will be used to create a new polygon layer.

As you can see, I've also tried to make use of the 'preload' setting when defining that source, but this doesn't seem to make any difference - although there is a good chance I'm doing that incorrectly.

Can my code be changed to make this work - or is there a better way of reading pixel values from a TileImage source without rendering the source as a layer on the map?

Comment: One option would be to use the TileImage as the source for an `ol.source.Raster` (whose operation always returns transparent).  Another would be to simply load the urls to canvas, similar to this but using the canvas to access pixels instead of saving the data.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607810/how-to-download-the-osm-tiles-for-selected-part-of-map

Comment: Thanks Mike - your answer in the link you've provided looks like it's going to be the way to go. Will give it a try and report back!